# Bootstrap not working on URL rewrite

Tags: php, url-rewriting, bootstrap-4

When I am using simple URL rewrite rule it works such as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home?$ index.php
```

It works but when I am using

```
RewriteRule ^buy-products/pages/([0-9]+)?$
product.php?buy&page=$1
```

It works but the problem is that while going to this page the bootstrap stops working...

Comment: Does the html that is targetted include the boostrap css and js dependancies (including jQuery)?

Comment: Bootstrap has nothing to do with URL rewrites

Comment: But the bootstrap is working without URL rewrite consider the normal URL is `mysite/products.php?buy&page=1` the bootstrap works in this but when I am accessing it as `mysite/products/page/1` the page loads but bootstrap doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you load the bootstrap css/js and other files in the html markup using site root path.

For example, if your domain is `your.com` and in the root of the document root of your site, you have two folders: `css` and `js` (i.e. http://your.com/css and http://your.com/js); then in your markup; use the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

So, regardless on the pages you are on, the resources will always be loaded from the root of the site. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: But the bootstrap is working without URL rewrite consider the normal URL is `mysite/products.php?buy&page=1` the bootstrap works in this but when I am accessing it as `mysite/products/page/1` the page loads but bootstrap doesn't